# Touch Application (WPF, C# VS 2010, Windows 7 for MS Samsung SUR 40 )

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010, multi-touch

I am developing a basic touch application for Surface mode using (WPF, C# VS 2010, Windows 7 on MS Samsung SUR 40). I can view the icon of my application in Surface Mode on the Launcher but am not able to run it. It shows the error of time-out and check with Surface SDK

I followed the steps as:

**Step 1)** To develop XAML and C# I used the following link to ove and rotate a rectangle.

"msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee649090.aspx"

Successfully build and run the project on windows mode without error

**Step 2)** I made the XML file to register my application for Surface mode using

"msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff727761.aspx"

I create a shortcut file (.lnk) that points to the application's XML file, and then put that shortcut file in the %PROGRAMDATA%\Microsoft\Surface\v2.0\Programs folder

**Step 3)** I also add the name of my application in ApplicationOrder.XML

**Step 4)** I click **Enter Surface Mode** to run the launcher and can view the Icon of my application.

But application isn’t running. It shows the error of time-out and check with Surface SDK. Please some one help how to fix this. Do I need some extra library to include or some other solutions.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In **Start->eventvwr-Applications and Services-Microsoft-Surface-Shell** :
*The application defined in App.xml failed to connect to Surface Shell within the expected amount of time*

The entry class for application is MainWindow which is inherited from Window. This correspond to a WPF application project template in VS so this is not correct for surface application.

This is a wrong project template for building Surface application. Recreate project with correct template as following steps:

1- Open Visual studio

2- Click on new project

3- From project template select  Visual C#

4- Then browse the tree  untill you find the node Surface

5- Then inside this Surface template, select 2.0 and from the list of template select Surface application (WPF)
[image]
[**Note:** If there is no surface mode (Step 1-5), then first download and install the **Surface SDK 2.0** ]

BE SURE TO SELECT CORRECT FRAMEWORK AS 4.0 for Surface 2.0

Then it will go and undertand by the Surface shell.

Hope it help. If yes please Vote and mark as answer

regards

Comment: Any idea how to open Word or Pdf (.doc/.pdf) document in the surface mode (using XAML and C#-WPF)?

Comment: http://sergecalderara.wordpress.com/2012/05/14/handling-an-xps-document-in-a-scatterview-surface-sur40/